# Finding Rows That Have The Same Value For A Given Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So out of all rows that I have in this table I think that there may be two rows that have the same value for a given field. Is there a way to determine which two rows those are?

Also, I don't know what the value would be.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to know which rows have the same value in a given column then you can find the duplicated column using the following

```
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*)
FROM   TableName
GROUP BY ColumnName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will show you the values that are duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the rows (as opposed to the value), I would recommend window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col) as cnt
      from mytable t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

This will return the actual rows, with an additional column for the count.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS Table INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table.ColumnToCompare=Table1.ColumnToCompare
```

If both "ColumnToCompare" have the same type, this should return the rows that have the same values.

Comment: if its the SAME table, then you'll run into ambigious column names.

Comment: @Simon is using an alias of `Table` and calling `Table1` a second time. he has the Syntax right. shouldn't be any issue here

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(*),Col1 From Table1 group by Col1 Having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ColumnToCompare, count(ColumnToCompare)
from table
where count(ColumnToCompare) > 1
```

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Gordon's answer but another way of solving this is:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.ColCnt
    FROM Tab T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Col, Count(*) AS ColCnt
                FROM Tab T GROUP BY Col 
                HAVING Count(*) > 1) T2
    ON T1.Col = T2.Col
```